# How can I speed up this Django query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this database filled with almost 2 million records, a lot of these are duplicated (different internal id but same 'idd')

Basically what I need is to query the database to get the first x records with only 1 product (distinct idd) and ordered by `'-sold_count'`

So this is the query I'm trying:

```
Product.objects.distinct('idd').order_by('idd', '-sold_count')[:2000]
```

Problem 1: That takes roughly 30 seconds, and I fear it will take longer with more data. How can I make it much faster?

Problem 2: Also it doesn't order it by sold_count descending, if anything it seems to be doing the opposite. How can I order it by -sold_count? Tried removing the '-' to experiment but results seem to be the same.

Other information:

idd is a CharField

sold_count is an IntegerField

Hope this is clear enough, if not you can ask any question you may have.

Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(default=False, null=True)
    sold_count = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    revenue = models.FloatField(default=False, null=True)
    idd = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    shipment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

**Raw Query sent:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("server_gitti"."idd") "server_gitti"."id", "server_gitti"."price", "server_gitti"."sold_count", "server_gitti"."revenue", "server_gitti"."idd", "server_gitti"."remaining", "server_gitti"."category", "server_gitti"."brand", "server_gitti"."seller", "server_gitti"."url", "server_gitti"."name", "server_gitti"."shipment", "server_gitti"."view_count", "server_gitti"."updated" FROM "server_gitti" ORDER BY "server_gitti"."idd" ASC, "server_gitti"."sold_count" ASC LIMIT 2000
```

Comment: Have you set indexes on any of those fields?

Comment: Problem 2 will be because its ordering by `idd` first. But I'm not sure I understand how you filter products with only one product

Comment: post the models. get the generated query, run it in psql as explain analyze query. post the out of that

Comment: `get the first x records with only 1 product (distinct idd)`.. what does it mean? Are you trying to get objects for one idd or different distinct idds? Or, do you mean that the first x records should have distinct idds and they should be sorted by in decreasing order of `sold_count`?

Comment: @Withnail I don't think I've set up any indexes.

Comment: @Sayse as I understand idd should be put in the order_by first because im using distinct='idd' and the second one should be the real order_by .. but im not really sure

Comment: @AKS Im trying to get all the objects of any idd but just 1 idd per dupliocate idd, and sorted by desc sold_count.

Comment: @e4c5 Ok i'll try to do that

Comment: @e4c5 Here's the output http://i.imgur.com/TO7pbon.jpg

Comment: sorry as text please

Comment: don't you have any indexes at all on this model?

Comment: Text: http://pastebin.com/ir99fGN3  I haven't made any additional indexes apart from the default ones. Not sure how to make them but I guess I should do it for idd

Comment: What is the value of Product.objects.all().count()

Comment: @ArundasR 1953241

Comment: Wow. Thats interesting. And you are using Postgres right?

Comment: What are the values you want from the database to be shown? That is do you want all the fields?

Comment: What Arundas said - do you need all of the fields?

Comment: Yes I need all the fields

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory resolution to this, @madprops?

Answer (score 3):

Well, one of the first things that I'd do, if I know I'm going to be searching on `TextField`s or `CharField` columns, is set an index:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField(default=False, null=True)
    sold_count = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    revenue = models.FloatField(default=False, null=True)
    idd = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True, db_index=True)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    shipment = models.CharField(max_length=300, default=False, null=True)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=False, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

[Django rocks uses a 2000 row example, entertainingly](https://www.djangorocks.com/snippets/indexing-your-django-models.html)

You may also want to have a look at the [SQL that Django's running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074224/1293222) - if you have extra methods on that class (or related classes), you might be triggering more SQL queries than you realise.  On the face of it, your query is pretty straightforward though, and that seems slow.  I run joins across a couple of million records that take that long on our crummy legacy database.  [I also had a similar issue on `get_or_create` queries on a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969171/slow-django-database-operations-on-large-ish-dataset) of tweets between those two sizes, which was solved by indexing.

Edit: 
Should have added the [standard django docs on optimisation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/) which has a couple of things to look out for as well.

Edit2: It looks like select distinct is generally fairly slow, and is a known problem on postgres.  Debugging through connection queries is [likely to yield some interesting results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33386881/1293222), though.

Comment: Thanks, I added db_index=True to idd and sold_count and migrated the changes. It took a while to migrate the changes. But it seems to not have affected the speed at all :/

Comment: Ugh. :( I was doing more background reading as I'm quite interested in this question - [this isn't encouraging, though.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1203934747.4252.10.camel@ebony.site).  Updated with some further background - have you run connections.queries, yet?

Comment: Hmm what exactly should I do with connection.queries? I just ran it and it showed a sql query. Tried to do the query after that, seemed to take the same time.

Comment: on postgresql after adding indexes you sometimes need to do VACUUM ANALYZE on that table

Comment: connection queries will show you whether it's running a fairly simple `distinct` command, per the other question I linked, or if it's running a more complicated/unnecessary.  Could be worth showing the raw SQL of what's being run in the question to help us/others run down the problem.

Comment: Added the query to the question. Which i got from print queryset.query

Comment: Ran VACUUM ANALYZE. Didn't seem to improve it